# Updating Cordova version on Android using Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

My cordova  version is out of date and I am receiving an error on google play that I won't be able to upload an app unless it's been updated. Well, I updated my cordova version in my OSX terminal and I'm currently running 5.2.0. When I check my project's cordova directory, it says it's at VERSION = 3.4.0.

How do I actually update the cordova version in my app that has already been built? I thought the correct command was `cordova platform update android` when I go to the specific directory. However, I'm receiving a "current working directory is not a cordova-based project" error.

Below is my directory; I have tried using just my main directory and also /cordova and /CordovaLib with no success. Can anyone help?

[image]

Comment: isn't that folder inside an android folder and the android folder inside platforms folder? If not, then you don't have a cordova project. create a new one and put your www content inside the new project

Comment: That is correct. This is in an androids folder which is in a platforms folder.

Comment: Then go to the folder that contains the platforms folder and type the cordova platform update there